# Kohana: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, kohana, autoload

Unable to start project in Kohana. I have cloned it from github, than set my database info in config file and get error: Cannot redeclare class.

I have 2 methods autoload functions.

```
public static function auto_load($class, $directory = 'classes')
    {
        // Transform the class name according to PSR-0
        $class     = ltrim($class, '\\');
        $file      = '';
        $namespace = '';

        if ($last_namespace_position = strripos($class, '\\'))
        {
            $namespace = substr($class, 0, $last_namespace_position);
            $class     = substr($class, $last_namespace_position + 1);
            $file      = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }

        $file .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);

        if ($path = Kohana::find_file($directory, $file))
        {
            // Load the class file
            require_once $path;


            // Class has been found
            return TRUE;
        }

        // Class is not in the filesystem
        return FALSE;
    }

    /**
     * Provides auto-loading support of classes that follow Kohana's old class
     * naming conventions.
     *
     * This is included for compatibility purposes with older modules.
     *
     * @param   string  $class      Class name
     * @param   string  $directory  Directory to load from
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public static function auto_load_lowercase($class, $directory = 'classes')
    {
        // Transform the class name into a path

        $file = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, strtolower($class));

        if ($path = Kohana::find_file($directory, $file))
        {
            // Load the class file
                require_once $path;


            // Class has been found
            return TRUE;
        }
        // Class is not in the filesystem
        return FALSE;
    }
```

I have tried to add class_exists() before require() but it doesn't work& What I should do to start a project?

Comment: Can you show full code example with `class_exists()` usage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly required class is included in some other file already.
I don't know how exactly you check class collision problem, but you should do something like:

```
function include_quietly($file) {
 $conflicts = false;
 $txt = file_get_contents($file);
 preg_match_all("#class\s+(\w+)\s*{#muis", $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

 foreach ($matches as $m) {
   if (class_exists($m[1])) {
     $conflicts = true;
     break;
   }
 }

 if (!$conflicts)
   include_once $file;
 else
   echo "include conflicts in file {$file}\n";
}

include_quietly($path);
```